# JS - Virtual pet evolution when user is not on application

Tags: javascript, mongodb, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using VueJS and MongoDB to create a virtual pet.

We're saving the user data using localStorage.

I'm wondering what the mechanism would be, to make the virtual pet evolve (ie. life gauge going down) when the user is not on the web app.
Would I need to save the date when the user leaves the app ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should save the time when the user leaves the app.

When they return (so, whenever you fetch data from the database), compare the saved time to the current time and apply whatever operations need to happen based on the difference.

Alternatively, you could have a server always running and deal with scheduled jobs and the like to keep it all updated in realtime, but lazy evaluation that only happens when the user requests the data should suffice for this case.